# Map JSON primitive to object value in Java

Tags: java, json, jackson

I have following JSON

```
{
  id: 1234,
  code: "N/A"
}
```

I would like to transform it to object of such classes:

```
class MySweetObject {
  int id;
  SomeStringWrapper code;
}

class SomeStringWrapper {
  String code;

  Boolean isNotAvailable() {
    return "N/A".equals(code);
  }
}
```

In short - I want to wrap simple property value from JSON in object to add some business functionality. Null value is not an option as `code` is a required property.

Is it possible to do it in Jackson?

Comment: initialize it in constructor ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [JsonSetter](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.7/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonSetter.html) annotation in `setCode` method:

From the documentation:

> Setter means that when a property with matching name is encountered in
>   JSON content, this method will be used to set value of the property

This way you could check if the value is `null` before setting it, and if it is `null` then set a default value (or do whatever you want).

Comment: Thanks mate! Works!

Comment: This will not work if there is no property `code` at all in the JSON data. From official documentation: `Setter means that when a property with matching name is encountered in JSON content, this method will be used to set value of the property.`

Comment: @Thomas.L yes you are right, but as far as I understand he always has `code` property in json and in some cases this property has value `null`

Comment: @amicoderozer Do you know how to achieve the same if I have a collection of SomeStringWrapper's in my root object?

Answer (score -1):

Try the following code:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.sun.javafx.fxml.PropertyNotFoundException;

class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        String jsonString = "{\"id\":\"1234\"}";
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        MySweetObject obj = mapper.readValue(jsonString, MySweetObject.class);
        System.out.println(mapper.writeValueAsString(obj));
    }
}

class MySweetObject {

    private String id;
    private String code;

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getCode() {
        if (code == null) {
            throw new PropertyNotFoundException("Property code cannot be null");
        } else {
            return code;
        }
    }
}
```

Normally `@JsonProperty(required = true)` would throw an exception, but It is not working, instead you can manually throw an exception in the getter if property is null or empty. check my code above, it will throw `JsonMappingException` if null.

Comment: I mentioned that `code` value is required and never be null

Comment: The main purpose of this question is to add extra logic for specific values like `"N/A"` inside wrapped value. And not to check if `code` is null. That's not the problem

Comment: well you just edited your question, so yeah... and instead of checking for null you can do what you want... this does exactly it

Comment: " Null value is not an option as code is a required property."  If this does not requires a null check what is it then? you need to check for null and empty

Answer (score -1):

You need to modify your JSON string, its wrong as per your classes. As the value "N/A" jackson will assume that to be a `string`, but that is the instance of `SomeStringWrapper` class.
Your JSON should look like as below in order to deserialize to your class structure:

```
{
  id: 1234,
  code: {
     code : "N/A"
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm aware of that. What I want to achieve is to make Jackson map this exact  property to wrapped string `code` property